# python regular exp wont match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract a up to 4 digits number out of the string (the 111) :

```
<td align=right><font color=yellow>Meldung:<td align=left><font  color=yellow>111</tr></table><p><table border width=90% cellpadding=3 bordercolor=darkgray><caption valign=top align=left>Aktuelle Messdaten bei Eintritt der St&ouml;rung</caption>
```

the string is everything, the regex should work with, since the document got split in lines

my regex is  `^r"<.*?><.*?>.*?<.*?><.*?yellow>"` for finding the beginning of the number. If I try it in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), it works, but if I use it in python, I get no match:

```
 numberBegin = re.search(r"^<.*?><.*?>.*?<.*?><.*?yellow>", tableRow).end(0) + 1
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Tp parse HTML, please consider using an HTML parser.

Comment: show a valid html markup fragment with top parent tag

Comment: thanks, I will consider it, but it doenst explain, why it doesn't match

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. Running the code above sets `numberBegin` to 79. It should be 78. I am not sure why you add 1 to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that `.*?` doesn't matches `\r\n`, which was somehow in the string but not shown by my IDE. I removed the `\r\n` and it works.